# Swift Array 'Object' does not have member named subscript

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object, multidimensional-array

So I'm pretty new to programming and I have 2 classes

1. Room
2. Maze (2d array)

On the viewcontroller I have `var mazeGame:Maze = Maze()`

Just above it on a blank line I have an error "Expected declaration"
My code down below is the main error I want to resolve "'Maze' does not have a member named subscript"

```
if (mazeGame[col][row].checkRoomNorthExit(row,col))
```

Also is there a way to create constructors in swift? Just so I can automatically call a chain of functions/methods to generate the maze when I start running it?

```
class Maze: NSObject {

    var mazeFloor = Array<Array<Room>>()

    var mazeSeed:UInt32 = 0
    var mazeSizeRows:UInt32 = 20
    var mazeSizeCol:UInt32 = 20
    var mazeRowPosition:UInt32 = 0
    var mazeColPosition:UInt32 = 0

    var startRow:Int = 0
    var startCol:Int = 0

    var endRow:Int = 0
    var endCol:Int = 0

    override init(){

    }

    func checkRoomNorthExit(rowPos: Int, colPos: Int) -> Bool{
        return mazeFloor[colPos][rowPos].getnorthExit()
    }
}
```

And in the Room class

```
class Room: NSObject {

    //Used for the 4 sides of the room
    var northExit = false
    var westExit = false
    var eastExit = false
    var southExit = false    

    func getnorthExit() -> Bool {
        return northExit
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your definition of Maze class? Also it will help if you will post the whole code, but not just a line from it. Thanks

Comment: You need to move this code in to your original post. That is to much code in a comment, it's extremely difficult to figure out what is actually happening there.

Comment: I added update to my post regarding how to access array that you need.  But I am sure there will be more errors that will need to be resolved. Looks like it just a beginning :)

Comment: For now I'd just like to focus on getting it working, will try to keep updating for anything else you guys need to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently mazeGame have a type Maze that does not implement subscript as result you can not access it by square brackets like you do in your if.

You should access rooms as following:

```
if (mazeGame.checkRoomNorthExit(row,col))
```

As for constructors you need to define init method for you class. Look into explanation of initialization in Swift book — https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: When I try to access rooms doing that I get an error saying "Could not find member 'checkRoomNorthExit'"

Comment: This mean you didn't define a method checkRoomNorthExit in your Room class. mazeFloor returns Room by the end, not the Maze. What is expected logic in this if? It is hard to guess it from the code.

Comment: I did another guess for the logic that you are trying to implement, did another edit :) But I need your advice in terms of what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: What I'm trying create is a 2d maze game using the view controller(trying to use one view to do it (using it as a main.cpp file like in C++)) and I'm trying to use this method to check to activate and deactivate the buttons on the view using .hidden. So I'm using this view to keep track of where the user/player is on the maze and displaying the options available in each room.

Comment: also just curious if I do it the way you have now, how does it know which Room in the 2d array I'm trying to access?

Comment: You passing coordinates to method which actially access mazeFloor array that contains room.

Comment: So since I answered your initial question, are we going to mark it answered or you have additional requests? :)